# "com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK" when using Picasso

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

As I was using the Picasso library in my Android Studio, the following error occurred:

Error:

```
'Execution failed for task :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.properties
File1: C:\Users\Abhiragh\AndroidStudioProjects\Reader\app\libs\picasso-2.5.2.jar
File2: C:\Users\Abhiragh\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.picasso\picasso\2.5.2\7446d06ec8d4f7ffcc53f1da37c95f200dcb9387\picasso-2.5.2.jar
```

I was able to build the project using the module apps Gradle file, but I could not run the project as the above error was showing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the library jar version as well as gradle version :

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

That's why this error is coming. remove any one of them and try again

Comment: Clean project, rebuild and run again .

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Picasso.Just add this lines to build.gradle

```
   packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.properties'
}
```

on android{} part.